# Slow to upload documents to a specific site collection

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2007, file-upload

We have an issue with SharePoint 2007 site collection when people upload documents to any document library it takes long time to upload whether the file is big or small, and once the file is uploaded and try to edit the document they get the following message:

[image]

It seems the issue is intermittent since it does not happen all the time. Is there a way to find the root cause of the issue?
Note: The site collection does not have its own DB and the DB is shared with 53 site collections.

Comment: how many server in the farm? do you unique permission on this site collection?

Comment: we have 6 servers in our MOSS farm. Again it seems to affect a particular site collection, other site collections are fine.

Comment: what is size of Site collection and what is size of Content DB? do you have customization on that site collection?

Comment: The size of the site collection is: 73579  MB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was related to another SharePoint Farm that we have in our environment crawling that farm in conjunction with another local crawl and that was putting load on the site and that is why we had the issue.

Make sure no other crawls are running from other sources. This is of course in our scenario.